# Web-scraping paginated website with difficult node

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, lubridate

I'm scraping the ASN database (http://aviation-safety.net/database/). I've written code to paginate through each of the years (1919-2019) and scrape all relevant nodes except fatalities (represented as "fat."). Selector Gadget tells me the fatalities node is called "'#contentcolumnfull :nth-child(5)'". For some reason ".list:nth-child(5)" doesn't work.

When I scrape #contentcolumnfull :nth-child(5), the first element is blank, represented as "".

How can I write a function to delete the first empty element for every year/page that's scraped? It's simple to delete the first element when I scrape a single page on its own:

```
fat <- html_nodes(webpage, '#contentcolumnfull :nth-child(5)')
fat <- html_text(fat)
fat <- fat[-1]
```

but I'm finding it difficult to write into a function.

I also have a second question regarding date-time and formatting. My days data are represented as day-month-year. Several element days and months are missing (ex: ??-??-1985, JAN-??-2004). Ideally, I'd like to transform the dates into a lubridate object, but I can't with missing data or if I only keep the years.

At this point, I've used gsub() and regex to clean the data (delete "??" and floating dashes), so I have a mixed bag of data formats. However, this makes it difficult to visualize the data. Thoughts on best practice?

```
# Load libraries 
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(httr)

years <- seq(1919, 2019, by=1)

pages <- c("http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=") %>%
  paste0(years) 

# Leaving out the category, location, operator, etc. nodes for sake of brevity 
read_date <- function(url){
  az <- read_html(url)
  date <- az %>%
    html_nodes(".list:nth-child(1)") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as_tibble()
} 

read_type <- function(url){
  az <- read_html(url)
  type <- az %>%
    html_nodes(".list:nth-child(2)") %>%
    html_text() %>%
    as_tibble()
}

date <- bind_rows(lapply(pages, read_date))
type <- bind_rows(lapply(pages, read_type))

# Writing to dataframe
aviation_df <- cbind(type, date)
aviation_df <- data.frame(aviation_df)

# Excluding data cleaning
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice to ping the same page more than once in order to extract the requested information.  You should read the page, extract all of the desired information and then move to the next page.

In this case the individual nodes are all store in one master table. rvest's `html_table()` function is handy to convert a html table into a data frame.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

years <- seq(2010, 2015, by=1)

pages <- c("http://aviation-safety.net/database/dblist.php?Year=") %>%
  paste0(years) 

# Leaving out the category, location, operator, etc. nodes for sake of brevity 
read_table <- function(url){
  #add delay so that one is not attacking the host server (be polite)
  Sys.sleep(0.5)
  #read page
  page <- read_html(url)
  #extract the table out (the data frame is stored in the first element of the list)
  answer<-(page %>% html_nodes("table") %>%  html_table())[[1]]
  #convert the falatities column to character to make a standardize column type
  answer$fat. <-as.character(answer$fat.)
  answer
} 

# Writing to dataframe
aviation_df <- bind_rows(lapply(pages, read_table))
```

The are a few extra columns which will need clean-up

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the advice about setting sys.sleep to go easy on the servers. 

eta: Also thanks for the tip about scraping the entire table. I was originally only going to scrape 3 nodes, but it seems easier to take the entire table then clean from there.